# Рандомный спаун конопок в Unity3D из префабов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите, есть префабы  5-ти кнопок с уникальной текстурой. Как их размещать в рандомной последовательности и после нажатия вывести в консоль результат последовательности нажатия кнопок?  
Считаю, что надо выводить не после нажатия последней кнопки, а предпоследней, ведь последняя кнопка уже в любом случае будет последней выбранной.

**Обновление**

Проблема в том, что не могу найти решение, как из массива заспаунить в случайном порядке кнопки без повторений, хороший пример - игра пятнашки. Сейчас у меня генерятся кнопки, но есть дубли (несколько одинаковых), а вот как проверять уже существующие и их не генерировать, не знаю.

Comment: @BamBool, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сохранять заспауненные кнопки в массив, а при спауне проверять массив на наличие кнопки с такой же текстурой. Вместо проверки по названиям текстур можно добавить поле с уникальным ID и проверять по нему.